# Code sharing between browser and server (inheritance)

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am writing a real-time multiplayer browser game in JavaScript. So I'm running JS on the server (Node.js) and in the browser. Because of that I would like to share code between those two contexts.

I decided to devide the code into three parts: Core, Client and Server. As you may have suspected I use Core for code we need on both sides, the Client and the Server.

Until now I have just been extending the corresponding core class, e.g. Client/Player extends Core/Player, which works just fine.

[image: UML]
Now I see that for example a Client/Player needs to extend the Core/Player to get the name attribute and at the same time it needs to extend Client/GameObject to get the render() method and the physics attribute.

If it was written in C++, I could try to use multiple inheritance with all its drawbacks. But since it is written in JavaScript, I'm not sure how to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was a hack with kind of a preprocessor. Before start I replace the require("Core/GameObject") in Core/Player with require(context + "/GameObject"). This way I create kind of a "z" which allows me to inherit from both.